# SSIS Oracle Source not pulling through Unicode characters correctly

Tags: sql-server, oracle, unicode, ssis

## Problem

I'm creating an SSIS package to move data from Oracle to SQL Server but am having trouble with certain Unicode characters.

Source Oracle database column is `NVARCHAR2` and an example character is `U+0102` but also applies to other characters. These will be migrated to an `NVARCHAR` column in SQL Server but the issue seems to be at the point of extraction as when I preview the source in SSIS the characters in question just show as inverted question marks e.g.

`DEMO¿DEMO`

## Setup

I'm using the Attunity - Oracle Source task/connection as couldn't get the OLE DB connection working

Oracle Database has `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16`

## Things I've tried

- Changing the `DefaultCodePage` value in Advanced settings of the Source task to `1252`, `65001`, `1200`, `1201`
- Converting the source column in the SQL command text in various ways, E.G.:  `Convert(SOURCE_COLUMN,'AL32UTF8')`
- Using `UTL_RAW.Convert_To_Raw` in the SQL Command text. This generates the correct binary values (as `DT_BYTES` in SSIS), but I couldn't then transform it back into a `DT_WSTR` using either Data Conversion or Derived Column.
- I've tested extracting the same characters from a SQL Server database and they are appearing correctly in the SSIS preview window just to rule out an SSIS issue.

I'm using the SQL Command access mode as per below:

```
SELECT SOURCE_COLUMN
FROM SOURCE_TABLE;
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you say the characters are odd in the preview window, but have you tried committing the copy into a SQL Server table and after the copy the Unicode characters are still not correct? What I'm trying to ask is, perhaps it's just the viewing window on data coming from Oracle? Also, this thread may or may not assist? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60067/why-does-ssis-oracle-source-by-attunity-return-dt-wstr-for-oracle-char1-column

Comment: Yes the characters were incorrect when committed to SQL, appearing as inverted question mark. I tried outputting to a flat file csv and had the same issue. I didn't fully follow that threat but the column in question is being output in SSIS as DT_WSTR which seems right to me. The source column is NVARCHAR2 with DATA_LENGTH of 60 and CHAR_LENGTH of 30.